# Print the highest value out of the minimums of list in dictionary

Tags: python

My current dictionary is:

```
{'NSW': [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.4, 0.5, 0.5, 54.6, 61.0, 3.4, 38.8, 2.8, 1.2, 0.5, 2.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 1.8, 0.4, 4.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.6, 10.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 6.0, 0.5, 3.0, 13.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 7.8, 16.4, 0.2, 3.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 34.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.6, 31.8, 4.4, 5.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 2.4, 2.8, 1.6, 7.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 1.8], 'QLD': [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 14.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 40.0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 4.4, 20.0, 0.6, 2.0, 3.4, 10.4, 9.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 3.4, 7.2, 0.4, 0.6, 4.6, 0.6, 0.6, 8.4, 18.4, 5.0, 6.1, 2.3, 16.8, 3.0, 0.4, 24.0, 10.8, 11.2, 9.8, 0.6, 23.8, 0.6, 0.2, 1.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 43.6, 6.8, 0.6, 20.8, 5.8, 10.6, 11.2, 5.4, 1.2, 0.6, 10.4, 1.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 4.4, 10.8, 5.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 5.2, 1.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 5.4, 5.8, 7.4, 9.8, 5.2, 10.4, 3.4, 0.6, 1.0, 9.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 2.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 3.0, 7.6, 5.0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.2, 2.0, 1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6], 'VIC': [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.4, 0.0, 0.0, 1.8, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 5.0, 0.6, 4.2, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 2.4, 2.0, 2.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.6, 0.0, 0.0, 4.2, 2.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.8, 2.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 7.2, 2.0, 0.6, 1.6, 0.0, 9.2, 0.6, 0.0, 7.8, 0.6, 0.0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 4.8, 0.8, 3.2, 1.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 2.0, 1.4, 0.0, 21.4, 0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 1.6, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.4, 0.2, 0.0, 2.4, 0.2, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 11.4, 0.2, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 4.4, 6.0, 0.4, 1.4, 1.4, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.6, 4.2, 0.0, 24.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]}
```

There are 3 keys, NSW, QLD and VIC.
I want to find the minimum out of each list, then print the highest number ouf these 'minimums' possibly through ascribing a value

THIS IS A SECTION of a larger question:
What I have done so far is,

```
rainfall_and_state = {}
is_first_line = True

for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    month = values[0].split("-")[1]
    rainfall = float(values[6])
    state = values[1]

    if state in rainfall_and_state:
      rainfall_and_state[state].append(rainfall)
    else:
      rainfall_and_state[state] = [rainfall]
```

## this section is wrong i think

```
minimum = {}
for key in rainfall_and_state:
  rainfalls = rainfall_and_state[key]
  minimum_rainfall = min(rainfall_and_state)
  minimum[key] = minimum_rainfall

print(rainfall_and_state)
```

if you want me to attach the larger question, I can do so if it better explains

Comment: Try `minimum_rainfall = min(rainfalls)`.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum of each list

```
>>> l = [(k, min(v)) for k,v in d.items()] 

[('VIC', 0.0), ('QLD', 0.2), ('NSW', 0.2)]
```

Max among them:

```
>>> max(x[1] for x in l)

0.2
```

To get the key, value:

```
>>> max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])

('QLD', 0.2)
```

Comment: sorry I'm confused as to what d.items is and the other letters for my specific code

Comment: I'm assuming d.items would be rainfall_and_state?

Comment: `d` is your dictionary, i.e. the variable which content is what you wrote in your first line in your question

Comment: Ahh ok, @RafaelC, so for my task, it says the program's output should look like " Month: 11, State: QLD". For month, it is because the 0.2 must have been in the month of novemeber from the earlier data set. SO how would I print QLD?

Comment: dict[key]  so i do something along those lines to print the key